# Out of sector combat in X3: how can I tell my ships to evade enemies?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude, x3-terran-conflict

As noted in a [related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132641/7508), out of sector combat can be a source of heartache and hassle.  In building my budding mercantile empire, I don't want to lose ships if I can avoid it.  I am aware of the MK3 Blacklist Manager and the emergency jump command but that's not exactly what I'm looking for:

- Blacklisting a sector is great for telling the ships "don't go into this war sector."  It's less useful in areas that are super useful / profitable but where maybe sometimes there's going to be a Xenon raid.
- Emergency jump is great as a last-ditch getaway but is too late if the enemy overwhelms you on the first salvo.

What I'd really like is to be able to tell a freighter "If an enemy M6 closes to within 10 KM, evade / change course / jump away."  I'd settle for "If you pick up a Big Bad at long range, jump away immediately."

Is this even possible within the existing suite of commands?  If not, is there a close-to-official mod that will give me a similar command set?

Comment: I think it should be possible to do with additional commands (same command type as mosquito missile defense), but I haven't seen any such scripts. My solution: use Springblossoms with cargo space cheated to 100k as traders. Those babies only ever get blown up in war sectors.

Comment: @kotekzot, thanks but I'm trying to play straight as much as possible.  I know about several interesting cheats but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish with this playthrough.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach is to make sure there's no Fight Command software on the ship, then it'll run away at the first sign of trouble because it has no other option.

Comment: That doesn't really fulfill the goal of "evade on detection."  Instead, your ships change course after being engaged.